# .NET Process.GetProcesses() "Access is denied."

Tags: c#, windows, process, system.componentmodel

I am trying to get a list of processes running on the current machine using the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Xynfo.Classes
{
    class Processes
    {
        //Gets list of processes running on local machine
        public static Process[] ProcessList = Process.GetProcesses(Environment.MachineName);

        //Creates the data table that will hold the process data
        public static DataTable ProcessTable = new DataTable();


         public  DataTable GetProcessesInfo()
        {

            //Create DataTable Columns

            ProcessTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            ProcessTable.Columns.Add("Start Time", typeof(DateTime));
            ProcessTable.Columns.Add("CPU %", typeof(TimeSpan));
            ProcessTable.Columns.Add("Threads", typeof(string));
            ProcessTable.Columns.Add("Session ID", typeof(int));
            ProcessTable.Columns.Add("Unique ID", typeof(int));
            ProcessTable.Columns.Add("RAM", typeof(float));
            ProcessTable.Columns.Add("Machine", typeof(string));
            ProcessTable.Columns.Add("Priority", typeof(int));




            foreach (Process Process in ProcessList)
            {
                string pName = Process.ProcessName;
                DateTime pStartTime = Process.StartTime;
                TimeSpan pProcTime = Process.TotalProcessorTime;
                string pThreads = Process.Threads.ToString();
                int pSessionId = Process.SessionId;
                int pId = Process.Id;
                long pRam = Process.VirtualMemorySize64;
                string pMachineName = Process.MachineName;
                int pPriority = Process.BasePriority;



                ProcessTable.Rows.Add(Process.ProcessName
                                     ,Process.StartTime
                                     ,Process.TotalProcessorTime
                                     ,Process.Threads
                                     ,Process.SessionId
                                     ,Process.Id
                                     ,Process.VirtualMemorySize64
                                     ,Process.MachineName
                                     ,Process.BasePriority);
            }

            return ProcessTable;

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception {"Access is denied."}
```

[image]

Do I need some kind of elevated privileges within the code? If so how do I do this?

Comment: As far as I remember doing the same thing, for some system processes not even administrative privileges are sufficient.

Comment: Try ti include the stack trace to see what line fails, but I think @ZoranHorvat is right.

Comment: Windows has restrictions on what data you can query from processes. You will have to properly handle the exceptions and show what are not allowed to the end users.

Answer (score 3):

Try to figure out which process it is. Maybe it is a system process that you don't need. Depends of your need of course. You can also try to run you application with elevated privileges (`Right click exe->Run as Administrator`)

```
foreach (Process Process in ProcessList)
{
    try
    {
        string pName = Process.ProcessName;
        DateTime pStartTime = Process.StartTime;
        TimeSpan pProcTime = Process.TotalProcessorTime;
        string pThreads = Process.Threads.ToString();
        int pSessionId = Process.SessionId;
        int pId = Process.Id;
        long pRam = Process.VirtualMemorySize64;
        string pMachineName = Process.MachineName;
        int pPriority = Process.BasePriority;



        ProcessTable.Rows.Add(Process.ProcessName
                             ,Process.StartTime
                             ,Process.TotalProcessorTime
                             ,Process.Threads
                             ,Process.SessionId
                             ,Process.Id
                             ,Process.VirtualMemorySize64
                             ,Process.MachineName
                             ,Process.BasePriority);
    }
    catch(Win32Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogWarning($"Error reading process {process.ProcessName}", e.Message);
    }
}
```